# wp divi nav-menu add polylang dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, polylang

The WP has installed DIVI theme and Polylang plugins. There are two languages, all pages published (translations included).

I created the second language menu and could not find the dropdown/switch when I did create it. Then I went to appearance and saw that the areas available for widgets where the side-bar and FOUR footers.

I can add the widget, but only appears at the footer. How can I make it so it appears on the nav-menu?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the Theme Customizer of Divi in Menus, you can tick the box (Language Switcher) from settings and then add the Language Switcher to your menus as an item.